# Web Scraping - iterating over

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to scrape a web-site hotel platform for reviews.
I cannot figure out two things:
1 - Why I cannot extract all reviews at one time? Say there are 14 reviews, I retrieve only 7 of them or so. I assume there is restriction by the server hosting the website?

2 - When I iterate over the object `review_list` the children objects that are retrieved are the same each time - i.e I retrieve the same `review_item`. Instead of iterating through the various objects the are `tag li` and of `class review_item` (see second code snippet).

I'm running Python 3.7 and an example url is:
[url example](https://www.booking.com/hotel/us/cozy-studio-on-theaters-district.en-gb.html?aid=304142;label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNYBGgxiAEBmAEuwgEDYWJuyAEO2AEB6AEB-AELkgIBeagCBA;sid=7860ef0f052cdf7b66e03d38cc2ff7b4;dest_id=20088325;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=1;group_children=0;hapos=9;hpos=9;nflt=class%3D1%3B;no_rooms=1;req_adults=1;req_children=0;room1=A;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=class_and_price;srepoch=1572010918;srpvid=72b46053510a0197;type=total;ucfs=1&#tab-reviews)
Hope you can shed some light here.

Thanks!

Code Snippet 1:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import json
import re
import sys
import warnings 
if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")#For ignoring SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE# url = input('Enter url - ' )
url=input("Enter Url - ")
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

html = soup.prettify("utf-8")

hotel_json_details = {}
hotel_json = {}
for line in soup.find_all('script',attrs={"type" : "application/ld+json"}):
    details = line.text.strip()
    details = json.loads(details)
    hotel_json_details["name"] = details["name"]
    hotel_json_details["aggregateRating"]={}
    hotel_json_details["aggregateRating"]["ratingValue"]=details["aggregateRating"]["ratingValue"]
    hotel_json_details["aggregateRating"]["reviewCount"]=details["aggregateRating"]["reviewCount"]
    hotel_json_details["address"]={}
    hotel_json_details["address"]["Street"]=details["address"]["streetAddress"]
    hotel_json_details["address"]["Locality"]=details["address"]["addressLocality"]
    hotel_json_details["address"]["Region"]=details["address"]["addressRegion"]
    hotel_json_details["address"]["Zip"]=details["address"]["postalCode"]
    hotel_json_details["address"]["Country"]=details["address"]["addressCountry"]

print(hotel_json_details)

div = soup.find_all(['li'],attrs={"class" : "review_item"})
print(div)
```

Code Snippet 2:

```
hotel_reviews= []
for line in soup.find_all('li', class_='review_item'): 
    review={}
    review["review_metadata"]={}
    review["review"]={}

    review["review_metadata"]["review_date"] = soup.find('p', class_='review_item_date').text.strip()
    review["review_metadata"]["review_staydate"] = soup.find('p', class_='review_staydate').text.strip()
    review["review_metadata"]["reviewer_name"] = soup.find('p', class_='reviewer_name').text.strip()
    review["review_metadata"]["reviewer_country"] = soup.find('span', class_='reviewer_country').text.strip()
    review["review_metadata"]["reviewer_score"] = soup.find('span', class_='review-score-badge').text.strip()
    review["review"]["review_pos"] = soup.find('p', class_='review_pos').text.strip()
    review["review"]["review_neg"] = soup.find('p', class_='review_neg').text.strip()
    scoreword = soup.find('span', class_='review_item_header_scoreword')
    if scoreword != None :
        review["review_metadata"]["review_header"] = scoreword.text.strip()
    else:
        review["review_metadata"]["review_header"] = ""
    hotel_reviews.append(x)
print(hotel_reviews)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are iterating over the review items, you need to use `line.find()` instead of `soup.find()`. This way, you'll be looking for review fields inside every review container as opposed to searching the whole HTML tree:

```
for line in soup.find_all('li', class_='review_item'): 
    review = {"review_metadata": {}, "review": {}}

    review["review_metadata"]["review_date"] = line.find('p', class_='review_item_date').text.strip()
    #                                          ^ HERE
```

Comment: @alecxe- so true! what a poor mistake.

Comment: Any idea why its retrieving only partial results ? as in only several reviews out of the total on the site for the single property? might this be a restriction by the server or something in my code?